# How to partially specialize a class template for all derived types?

Tags: c++, derived-class, partial-specialization, crtp

I want to partially specialize an existing template that I cannot change (`std::tr1::hash`) for a base class and all derived classes. The reason is that I'm using the curiously-recurring template pattern for polymorphism, and the hash function is implemented in the CRTP base class. If I only want to partially specialize for a the CRTP base class, then it's easy, I can just write:

```
namespace std { namespace tr1 {

template <typename Derived>
struct hash<CRTPBase<Derived> >
{
    size_t operator()(const CRTPBase<Derived> & base) const 
    { 
        return base.hash(); 
    }
};

} }
```

But this specialization doesn't match actual derived classes, only `CRTPBase<Derived>`. What I want is a way of writing a partial specialization for `Derived` if and only if it derives from `CRTPBase<Derived>`. My pseudo-code is

```
namespace std { namespace tr1 {

template <typename Derived>
struct hash<typename boost::enable_if<std::tr1::is_base_of<CRTPBase<Derived>, Derived>,
    Derived>::type>
{
    size_t operator()(const CRTPBase<Derived> & base) const 
    { 
        return base.hash(); 
    }
};

} }
```

...but that doesn't work because the compiler can't tell that `enable_if<condition, Derived>::type` is `Derived`. If I could change `std::tr1::hash`, I'd just add another dummy template parameter to use `boost::enable_if`, as recommended by the `enable_if` documentation, but that's obviously not a very good solution. Is there a way around this problem? Do I have to specify a custom hash template on every `unordered_set` or `unordered_map` I create, or fully specialize `hash` for every derived class?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two variants in the following code. You could choose more appropriated for you.

```
template <typename Derived>
struct CRTPBase
{
    size_t hash() const {return 0; }
};

// First case 
//
// Help classes
struct DummyF1 {};
struct DummyF2 {};
struct DummyF3 {};
template<typename T> struct X; 

// Main classes
template<> struct X<DummyF1> : CRTPBase< X<DummyF1> > {
    int a1;
};

template<> struct X<DummyF2> : CRTPBase< X<DummyF2> > {
    int b1;
};

// typedefs
typedef X<DummyF1> F1;
typedef X<DummyF2> F2;
typedef DummyF3    F3; // Does not work

namespace std { namespace tr1 {
    template<class T>
    struct hash< X<T> > {
        size_t operator()(const CRTPBase< X<T> > & base) const     
        {         
            return base.hash();     
        }
    };
}} // namespace tr1 // namespace std 

//

// Second case
struct DummyS1 : CRTPBase <DummyS1> {
    int m1;
};
//
template<typename T> 
struct Y : T {};
//
typedef Y<DummyS1> S1;


namespace std { namespace tr1 {
    template<class T>
    struct hash< Y<T> > {
        size_t operator()(const CRTPBase<T> & base) const     
        {         
            return base.hash();     
        }
    };
}} // namespace tr1 // namespace std 

void main1()
{
    using std::tr1::hash;
    F1 f1;
    F2 f2;
    F3 f3;
    hash<F1> hf1; size_t v1 = hf1(f1); // custom hash functor
    hash<F2> hf2; size_t v2 = hf2(f2); // custom hash functor
    hash<F3> hf3; size_t v3 = hf3(f3); // error: standard hash functor

    S1 s1;
    hash<S1> hs1; size_t w1 = hs1(s1); // custom hash functor

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of modifying `std::tr1::hash` you should make your own namespace and define there new structure `hash` which inherited from `std::tr1::hash` or is specialized for `CRTPBase<Derived>`.

```
template <typename Derived>
struct CRTPBase
{
    size_t hash() {return 0; }
};

struct AA : CRTPBase <AA> {};
struct BB {};
//
namespace mynamespace {

template <typename Some, typename Dummy=char> 
struct hash : std::tr1::hash<Some> {};
//
template <typename Derived>
struct hash<Derived, 
  typename boost::enable_if< std::tr1::is_base_of<CRTPBase<Derived>, Derived>, char>::type >
{    
    size_t operator()(const CRTPBase<Derived> & base) const     
    {         
        return base.hash();     
    }
};

} // namespace mynamespace {}
//
//
void ff()
{
    using namespace mynamespace;

    hash<AA> aa;  // my hash
    hash<BB> bb;  // std::tr1::hash

}
```

Comment: But then he still has to specify a custom hash template on every unordered_set, since it won't be using his namespace.

Answer (score 0):

C++20 edition:

```
#include <concepts>
#include <functional>
#include <unordered_set> // just for demo in main()

template <class T>
class Base {};

class Derived final : public Base<Derived> {};

template<class T>
requires std::derived_from<T, Base<T>>
struct std::hash<T> {
  // constexpr is optional
  constexpr size_t operator() (const T& value) const noexcept {
    return 0xDEADBEEF; // FIXME: do something better :)
  }
};

int main() {
  // If operator() weren't constexpr, this couldn't be a *static* assert
  static_assert(std::hash<Derived>()(Derived {}) == 0xDEADBEEF);
  std::unordered_set<Derived> usageTest;
  return 0;
}
```