# template specialization for all subclasses

Tags: c++, templates, subclass, template-specialization

I would like to define a C++ template specialization that applies to all subclasses of a given base class. Is this possible?

In particular, I'd like to do this for STL's hash<>. hash<> is defined as an empty parametrized template, and a family of specializations for specific types:

```
template<class _Key>
  struct hash { };

template<>
  struct hash<char>
  {
    size_t
    operator()(char __x) const
    { return __x; }
  };

template<>
  struct hash<int>
  {
    size_t
    operator()(int __x) const
    { return __x; }
  };
...
```

I would like to define something like this:

```
template<class Base>
  struct hash {
    size_t operator()(const Base& b) const {
      return b.my_hash();
    }
  };

class Sub : public Base {
  public:
    size_t my_hash() const { ... }
};
```

and be able to use it like this:

```
hash_multiset<Sub> set_of_sub;
set_of_sub.insert(sub);
```

However, my hash template conflicts with the generic one from STL. Is there a way (perhaps using traits) to define a template specialization that applies to all subclasses of a given base class (without modifying the STL definitions)?

Note that I know I can do this with some extra template parameters whenever this hash specialization is needed, but I'd like to avoid this if possible:

```
template<>
  struct hash<Base> {
    size_t operator()(const Base& b) const {
      return b.my_hash();
    }
  };

....

// similar specialization of equal_to is needed here... I'm glossing over that...
hash_multiset<Sub, hash<Base>, equal_to<Base> > set_of_sub;
set_of_sub.insert(sub);
```

Comment: if its conflicting why not use a namespace ?

Comment: A possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032973/how-to-partially-specialize-a-class-template-for-all-derived-types

Comment: ... where the solution is to name all the derived classes in a similar way, which is not quite satisfactory.

Answer (score 1):

Since **C++ 11** you can use [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) together with standard library [enable_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) and [is_base_of](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of) to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

C++20 makes a cleaner solution possible - basically equivalent to enable_if, which even (optionally) works with CRTP

```
#include <concepts>
#include <functional>
#include <unordered_set> // just for demo in main()

template <class T>
class Base {};

class Derived final : public Base<Derived> {};

template<class T>
requires std::derived_from<T, Base<T>>
struct std::hash<T> {
  // constexpr is optional
  constexpr size_t operator() (const T& value) const noexcept {
    return 0xDEADBEEF; // FIXME: do something better :)
  }
};

int main() {
  // If operator() weren't constexpr, this couldn't be a *static* assert
  static_assert(std::hash<Derived>()(Derived {}) == 0xDEADBEEF);
  std::unordered_set<Derived> usageTest;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use SFINAE to decide whether or not to allow your specialisation depending on the class inheritance structure. In Boost you can use `enable_if` and `is_base_of` to implement this.

- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/utility/enable_if.html
- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_base_of.html

Comment: I'm afraid you can't use `enable_if` in this particular case.

Comment: jpalecek: Why not? BTW, if boost is the answer here, it might not help me anyway, since my workplace restricts the libraries we can use, and boost::enable_if is not part of the prescribed subset.

Comment: Then you may have to roll your own, but you should be able to get something that works as you want by using SFINAE.

Comment: This response doesn't actually give an answer to the OP question.

Answer (score 0):

This was the best I could do:

```
template<>
  struct hash<Sub> : hash<Base> {
  };
```

I'm a little worried that I didn't have to make `operator()` virtual, though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible, because the way to do template specialization based on something more complex than just matching the type is C++ SFINAE, which requires second (dummy) template argument. Unfortunatelly, `std::hash` takes only one template argument and it is not allowed to create another version of `std::hash` with two template arguments. Therefore, the if you aren't satisfied with [Jayen's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7621856/template-specialization-for-all-subclasses/9173065#9173065), you can create your own `hash` type:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

class ParentClass {};
class ChildClass : public ParentClass {};

// SFINAE, if T is not a child of ParentClass, substitution will fail
// You can create specializations for the general case, for another base classes, etc.
template<typename T, typename=typename enable_if<is_base_of<ParentClass, T>::value, T>::type>
struct your_hash
{
    size_t operator()(const T& value)
    {
        return 42;
    }
};

int main()
{
  ParentClass pc;
  ChildClass cc;
  cout<<your_hash<ParentClass>()(pc)<<"\n";
  cout<<your_hash<ChildClass>()(cc)<<"\n";
}
```